# Joining line features of streets and parking lots?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have a feature class (line) that include street and parking lots. How would I create it so that wherever the parkinglot touches the street - it creates a merged drawing (so it doesn't look like there is a wall there instead it flows through)? Picture of what it looks like now is below.[image]